# How to use sed to remove all trailing Q's, but not remove the last Q if the line is all Q's

Tags: sed

I am processing a file from a commercial vendor that uses the letter Q as placeholder at the end of each line.  I need to remove all Q's at the end of each line, with the exception that it should never remove everything from a line.  If a line is all Q's, it should leave a single Q.

I use this sed code to remove all trailing Q's...

```
line=$( echo $line | sed 's/Q*$//' )
```

...but it doesn't handle the case where the line is all Q's, where it should leave 1 Q.  I can add the Q back, of course, with this code...

```
if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    line="Q"
fi
```

...but I want to learn how to handle this case entirely in sed for future reference.  Sample outputs:

```
TESTQQQQQQ --> TEST
QQQ        --> Q
```

Comment: @Cyrus, that leaves a line with all Q's completely untouched.  I tried a similar tack, but couldn't get it to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
  sed 's/\(.\)Q*$/\1/'
```

Roughly, this replaces any single character `.` with zero or more Q's to the end of line with the single character, using `\1`, saved via the `\(` and `\)`. It works because `sed` is "greedy".

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you could try:

```
awk '/^Q+$/{print "Q"; next} {gsub(/Q+$/,"")} 1' prueba.txt
```

I assuming that you only have one word for line, if it's not the case let me know.

Comment: Nice work, that does seem to do the trick.  I know much less about awk compared to sed/grep, so I never thought to use that.

Comment: That has several issues  (`Q` is already literal so no need for `[Q]`, the first arg for gsub() is a regexp not a string, $0 is what gets printed by default, etc.), not least of which is it'll remove Qs from the middle of each line, not just at the end.

Comment: I just change the line, what do you think now?. Thanks for feedback.